# Установка pip discord

Tags: python, discord, pip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as{0}'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self , message):
        print('Message from{0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

client = Myclient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

**Ошибка:**

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: **НИКОГДА** не показывайте свой токен в интернете! Рекомендую срочно его [сменить](https://discord.com/developers/applications) , пока к вашему боту не получили доступ другие пользователи

Comment: @denisnumb назовем этого бота бесполезным ведь мне не могут даже помочь с проблемой сам вчера сидел думал что сделать но так и не получилось сделать его активным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам поможет установка [Microsoft Visual C++](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

---

Еще рекомендую обновить `pip` и `discord`

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade discord
```

или

```
pip install discord-py
```

Также, до правок, внесенных в код из вашего вопроса, у вас в строке `client,run('TOKEN')` вместо запятой должна быть точка. Возможно просто опечатка, но все же стоит обратить внимание :)

---

**Дополнено:** помог переход с `Python 3.9` на `Python 3.8.3`

Comment: ничего из этого не помогло думаю может переустановить просто сам питон

Comment: @German, можете, пожалуйста, дополнить вопрос полным кодом ошибки?

Comment: не знаю как редактировать может куда то удобнее вам прислать можно?

Comment: код содержит что то ужасное)

Comment: Ну, я понимаю, просто хотелось бы глянуть на полный код ошибки

Comment: можно вам куда то в лс отправить?

Comment: Если честно, не знаю как здесь открывать чат (хотя он есть), так что лучше просто добавьте на время в текст вопроса, потом можно будет убрать. Если там что-то совсем ужасное)

Comment: он не дает отправить саму ошибку

Comment: а какая причина?

Comment: я скинул скрин чуть повыше , если нужно будет еще выше я редактирую еще раз

Comment: Думаю, да. Переустановка python до последней версии (вместе со всеми модулями) должна помочь. Но `Microsoft Visual C++` вроде как тоже нужен

Comment: я скачал какой то майкрасофт уже

Comment: я сдаюсь , мне ничего уже не помогает даже переустановка

Comment: Вы установили `Microsoft Visual C++`?

Comment: да я установил его